# Prove or disprove that there exists a constant $K$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq K |x-y|,\;\;\forall\;\;x,y\in[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits, lipschitz-functions

I'm preparing for my final exam and I want to solve as many questions as possible. However, I don't know how to tackle this question. Please, can anyone help me out?

Let $f$ be a function on $[0,1]$ into $\Bbb{R}$. Suppose that if $x\in[0,1],$ there exists $K_x$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq K_x |x-y|,\;\;\forall\;\;y\in[0,1]$
Prove or disprove that there exists a constant $K$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq K |x-y|,\;\;\forall\;\;x,y\in[0,1]$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is disproven by, for instance,
$$
f(x)=\cases{0& if $x=0$\\x\sin(1/x)& otherwise}
$$
To elaborate, $f$ has unbounded derivative, meaning it's not Lipschitz.

However, for each $x$ there is a $K_x$. Indeed, $K_0=1$ works, and for $x\in(0,1]$, let $x_0\leq x$ be such that $f'$ has a local maximum or minimum at $x_0$. Then $K_x=|f'(x_0)|$ works.

Comment: Thank you very much! Please, can you elaborate further?

Comment: @Mike I added a small elaboration.