# Proof explanation: Prove or disprove that $\exists\;K$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq K|x-y|,\;\;\forall\; x,y\in [0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation, lipschitz-functions

Sometime ago, I asked the following question [Prove or disprove that there exists a constant $K$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq K |x-y|,\;\;\forall\;\;x,y\in[0,1]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2788151/prove-or-disprove-that-there-exists-a-constant-k-such-that-fx-fy-leq-k) and was answered. However, I did not really understand this line

"However, for each $x$ there is a $K_x$. Indeed, $K_0=1$ works, and for $x\in(0,1]$, let $x_0\leq x$ be such that $f'$ has a local maximum or minimum at $x_0$. Then $K_x=|f'(x_0)|$ works."

Please, can anyone please give me a detailed explanation?

Comment: That should be a comment below the answer to your former question that you claim now you did not understand then, despite having accepted the answer.  Ask the author of the answer.

Comment: Indeed, you should be asking [Arthur this question, below his answer to your question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2788160/9003)

Comment: Else, this question is coming virtually close to being a duplicate of your already posted question.

Comment: Another  interesting point is  that even if $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ is strictly monotonic and everywhere differentiable, its derivative  may be unbounded on $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $f$ is bounded and differentiable on $[a,b].$ Then for every $x\in [a,b]$ there exists such a constant $K_x.$

Proof: Let $M=\sup_{[a,b]}|f|.$ Fix $x\in [a,b].$ Then there is a neighborhood $I_x$ of $x$ such that

$$\tag 1 \left |\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}\right | \le |f'(x)| + 1\,\, \text { for } y\in I_x\setminus\{x\}.$$

This follows from the definition of $f'(x).$ Now there there is $\delta > 0$ such that $|y-x|\ge \delta$ for $y\in [a,b]\setminus I_x.$ For such $y$ we have

$$\tag 2 \left |\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}\right | \le \frac{2M}{\delta} <\infty.$$

From $(1),(2)$ the existence of $K_x$ follows.